# Mount a remote Raspberry Pi filesystem over SSH

Tags: mount, fstab

I want to mount pi share on another pi. I tried this:

`sudo nano /etc/fstab && sudo mount -a`

And in fstab I added:

```
pi@files.home:/mnt/4TB/ /mnt/files fuse.sshfs defaults,allow_other,_netdev 0 0
```

And I get the error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on pi@files.home:/mnt/4TB/,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I guess I'm using the wrong arguments, But I don't know what are the correct arguments. What are the correct arguments? Where do I look?

Comment: please have a look at https://superuser.com/a/669295/201468

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used raspbian lite, and `sshfs`isn't installed by default.

So I installed it with `sudo apt-get install sshfs`

Then I added it to the `/etc/fstab`

```
pi@192.168.2.95:/mnt/4TB/ /mnt/files  fuse.sshfs  identityfile=/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,defaults,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

So now the files are available on the remote Raspberry Pi via `sshfs` (SSH File System).

Comment: if this fixed your problem, you can mark it as an answer.